# .htaccess redirecting when file doesn't exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess to redirect users to my main controller and it is working fine. But when i call a js file that doesn't exist like:

```
<script src="/js/jquery1231231312.js"></script>
```

Instead of just says 404 - file doesn't exists, this js file is getting the content of index.php. How should i proceed?

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does `/js/jquery1231231312.js` exist? when you look in your `/js` folder, is there a file called `jquery1231231312.js`?

Comment: no, that file doesn't exists!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the way that you have it setup, everything gets routed through `index.php`. If a request is made for a resource that doesn't exist, it gets routed through `index.php`. It's up to index.php to realize something's not there, and return a 404 error, but I'm guessing it's setup so that if the `url=` doesn't exist, to returns the home page.

You can change your rules to ignore the routing for certain files, like for your example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This would make it so nothing in the `/js` directory will ever get routed through `index.php`, so if someone requests a non-existing file in the `/js` directory, they'll just get the regular 404 response.

---

EDIT:

> That's what I want, to ignore the routing for certain files (js, css, images), because then if the files doesn't exists i would get the normal error!

If you want to ignore all images, javascript, and css, then the 2nd line should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|css|js)$ [NC]
```

Comment: That's what I want, to ignore the routing for certain files (js, css, images), because then if the files doesn't exists i would get the normal error! I tried what you said but it didn't worked!

Comment: That way work like a charm! Is this the best way to do that? My code is very similar to cakePHP framework, i saw that they don't do this RewriteCond, and when i try to attempt this error on their framework, it worked fine! http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess

Comment: For those who get an apache error like `Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand`, try to add a leading slash to index.php like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`